# Ubuntu 16.04: How to get libx86emu x86emu-demo to work?

Tags: qemu, emulation, emulators

**Does anyone know how to get libx86emu x86emu-demo to work?**

https://github.com/wfeldt/libx86emu

```
Test.bin
00000000 55 8B EC 51 C7 45 FC 00 00 00 00 8B 45 FC 50 E8 
00000010 09 00 00 00 83 C4 04 33 C0 8B E5 5D C3 55 8B EC 
00000020 B8 01 00 00 00 5D C3

00: 55                      push   ebp
01: 8b ec                   mov    ebp,esp
03: 51                      push   ecx
04: c7 45 fc 00 00 00 00    mov    DWORD PTR [ebp-0x4],0x0
0b: 8b 45 fc                mov    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp-0x4]
0e: 50                      push   eax
0f: e8 09 00 00 00          call   0x1d
14: 83 c4 04                add    esp,0x4
17: 33 c0                   xor    eax,eax
19: 8b e5                   mov    esp,ebp
1b: 5d                      pop    ebp
1c: c3                      ret
1d: 55                      push   ebp
1e: 8b ec                   mov    ebp,esp
20: b8 01 00 00 00          mov    eax,0x1
25: 5d                      pop    ebp
26: c3                      ret
```

./x86emu-demo -l 0 -s 0 Test.obj

I need to be able to execute x86 machine code similar to the above sample. libx86emu decodes and executes the first three instructions then decodes the fourth instruction incorrectly. I only need to be able to emulate 32-bit x86, I don't need any OS support.

Only about half of the libx86emu x86test regression tests pass.

Comment: I am trying to get it to run on UBUNTU 16.04

Comment: I answered this here a few years ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59473317/ubuntu-16-04-getting-libx86emu-x86emu-demo-to-work/59779467#59779467

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/wfeldt/libx86emu/issues/25

The author of libx86emu "Steffen Winterfeldt" updated: libx86emu/demo/x86emu-demo.c so that it now has a "32-bit mode" command line parameter.

Previously the code executed in the default 16-bit mode.